# If else statement in elasticsearch query construction

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I'm using elasticsearch php  and trying to optimize my query contraction in one place. Typical Elasticsearch query like:

```
$params = [
    'index' => 'my_index',
    'type' => 'my_type',
    'body' => [
        'query' => [
            'bool' => [
                'must' => [
                    [ 'match' => [ 'testField' => 'abc' ] ],
                    [ 'match' => [ 'testField2' => 'xyz' ] ],
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

So the question is, does it possible to put conditional query in $params before 'match' string maybe like:

```
<?php if (isset($_GET['query'])) [ 'match' => [ 'testField' => 'abc' ] ]; ?>
```

Thank you in any advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
 <?php
 $must = [[ 'match' => [ 'testField2' => 'xyz' ] ] ];
 if (isset($_GET['query']))
     $must[] = [ 'match' => [ 'testField' => 'abc' ] ];

 $params = [
     'index' => 'my_index',
     'type' => 'my_type',
     'body' => [
         'query' => [
             'bool' => [
                 'must' => $must
             ]
         ]
    ]
 ];
```

or this;

```
 <?php
 $params = [
     'index' => 'my_index',
     'type' => 'my_type',
     'body' => [
         'query' => [
             'bool' => [
                 'must' => [
                      [ 'match' => [ 'testField2' => 'xyz' ] ],
                 ],
             ]
         ]
    ]
 ];

 if (isset($_GET['query']))
     $params['body']['query']['bool']['must'][] = [ 'match' => [ 'testField' => 'abc' ] ];
```